# SUMPRODUCT function with IF logic

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am attempting to multiple two arrays, but only if array 2 meets a greater than or equal to criteria. That criteria is >=243

---

### | Array 1      | Array 2            |

### | 5         | 200 |

### | 5    | 240 |

### | 5 | 280 |

### | 5 | 320 |

I have attempted to use the following formula: 
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Program!F4:F8>=(VLOOKUP(Results!$C$10,Start!$B$3:$H$8,4,0)*Results!E22)),Program!E4:E8)

Which is simplified to:
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Program!F4:F8>=243)),Program!E4:E8)

This returns the number 10, which I assume is because it returns the true values as 1, and then are multiplied by 5 and summed.

How may I fix this to return 3000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just add the first array to your formula another time,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F2:F5>=243)*(E2:E5)*(F2:F5))
```

(F2:F5>=243) creates an array of 1 or 0, and the result of that must be multiplied with (F2:F5).

Comment: Thank you! This appears to work, I was able to return 3000 with =SUMPRODUCT((Program!F2:F5>=(VLOOKUP(Results!$C$10,Start!$B$3:$H$8,4,0)*Results!E22))*(Program!E2:E5)*(Program!F2:F5))

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as Variatus's post except it avoids the, in my opinion, odd choice to multiply the parameters inside the sumproduct function, which handles the multiplication. I've also explicitly converted the first logical array to number.

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(F2:F5>=243),E2:E5,F2:F5)`

Comment: I can confirm this works as well! Thank you. This does seem a bit simpler to the prior solution.